# Neo4j import tool (Bulk) - Why is the restart required?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-batch-inserter

This question came up on our team a few times.I don't know the real answer.
Can someone point out in the right direction to better understand why restart is needed after bulk importing CSV files?

Or is there an option to tell neo4j to silently point to new DB folder and no restart?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The import utility creates a previously non-existent database. Offline (that's the whole point), so Neo4j can not be running on that database and the resulting folder can not exist beforehand. So even if you use the default folder name (graph.db) you have to start Neo4j after the import. Or change neo4j.conf to point to the newly created folder and then start Neo4j. Either way you have to start/restart Neo4j ... changes to the configuration are not picked up by the software.

Hope this helps,

Regards,
Tom

Comment: with default name graph.db. the name is already available to the neo4j right.  I may sound silly - if it's just a matter of knowing the directory name. Can I just not remove old "graph.db" and put new "graph.db" and expect changes to be seen in without restart (haven;t tried this yet)?

Comment: Yes ... (and that's implied in my answer in fact) ... but you can not do an offline (key word) import in a running database. So however you slice or dice it ... at the end you'll have to do at least a start.